# RESTFUL webservice spring, XML in stead of JSON?

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, rest

I am trying to return an object as XML in spring, exactly like this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Except that I want the object to return as xml instead of JSON.

Anyone know how I can do that? 
Does Spring have any dependancies that can do this as easily for XML? Or, do I need to use a marshaller and then return the xml file some other way?

Comment: its not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026928/spring4-0-rest-service-not-working-for-xmlresponse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use JAXB annotations in your bean to define `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` then it should marshall it xml. Spring will marshall the bean to xml when it sees:

- Object annotated with JAXB
- JAXB library existed in classpath
- “mvc:annotation-driven” is enabled
- Return method annotated with @ResponseBody

Follow this sample to know more:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/

Comment: @mikhail90 The `@ResponseBody` on its own will not be enough if there is a `HttpMessageConverter` setup for JSON. Basically, Spring will use the first one it finds that can perform the conversion. A safe way is to return a `ResponseEntity` with `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`

Answer (score 11):

Spring supports JSON by default, but to support XML as well, do these steps -

1. In the class you plan to return as response, add xml annotations. for e.g.

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "response")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) => this is important, don't miss it.
    public class Response {
        @XmlElement
        private Long status;
        @XmlElement
        private String error;

        public Long getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Long status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getError() {
            return error;
        }

        public void setError(String error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

2. Add produces and consumes to your **@RequestMapping** on the restful method like below, this helps in making sure what kind of responses and request you support, if you only want response as xml, only put produces = "application/xml".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/xml", "application/json"}, produces = {"application/xml", "application/json"})
```

public

3. Then, make sure you return the response object from your method call like below, you can add @ResponseBody just before return type but in my experience, my app worked fine without it.

```
public Response produceMessage(@PathVariable String topic, @RequestBody String message) {
    return new Response();
}
```

4. Now, if you are supporting multiple produces types, then based on what client sent as the **Accept** in the HTTP request header, the spring restful service will return that type of response. If you only want to support xml, then only produce 'application/xml' and the response will always be xml.

Comment: if i use the same Entity for Json and Xml, how can i do it ?

Comment: As far as I know, Spring support JSON by default, so you can use the same entity and just annotate it with both xml annotations as suggested above. You just need to use produces = {"application/xml", "application/json"} in your request mapping to support both or any one of the types for you entity. Now if the client request JSON content type, response will be sent in JSON.